# Can a sheet be made active using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, numbers

I'm wanting to activate a particular sheet in Numbers using AppleScript. I know that if a table is on the sheet then it can be activated by doing something like this:

```
tell the table 1 of sheet 2 of document "Document"
    set value of cell 1 of column "A" to "x"
end tell
```

but what if there isn't a table and only a chart? Is there a way to activate a sheet if it only contains a chart?

Comment: Thanks @user3439894
Just what I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```applescript
tell application "Numbers" to ¬
    set active sheet of ¬
        document 1 to ¬
        sheet 1 of ¬
        document 1
```

Obviously, change the *value* of the *elements* as appropriate.

You can also use this *syntax*:

```applescript
tell application "Numbers"
    tell document 1
        set active sheet to sheet 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Again, change the *value* of the *elements* as appropriate.